# Why is my image not showing in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and am slowly learning it. I looked through these forums in search of an answer to my question yet nothing I tried worked. Here's the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <br>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="boxa"> </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.boxa {
  display: block;
  background:url(C:\Users\Sidworld\Desktop\App-Google-icon.png);
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  -webkit-transition:width 0.1s, height 0.1s, background-color 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition:width 0.1s, height 0.1s, background-color 0.4s, transform 0.1s;
}

.boxa:hover {
  background:url(..\Desktop\App-Google-icon.png);
  width:1024px;
  height:1024px;
}
```

I'm new here so please bear with the bad formatting.
The image is on my desktop and i have checked it.

Comment: You have an extra closing `</head>` tag. Remove the first instance of this so your CSS will actually be called. As it is, your `link rel` line is technically outside of your `head` section.

Comment: How would you display `C:\Users\Sidworld\Desktop\App-Google-icon.png` on another machine?

Comment: @TylerH this is not a problem. `link` will be placed inside `head` element anyway, even if `head` has been closed before `link` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
background: url(C:\Users\Sidworld\Desktop\App-Google-icon.png);
```

to

```
background-image: url("/Users/Sidworld/Desktop/App-Google-icon.png");
```

Never use `\`. Backslash is the escape character, so a single `\` usually doesn't mean what you think it means.

Windows has understood `/` for years. Even if you are working locally, you can safely use `/` in place of `\` and be more portable.

Also, `C:` is another Windows-only thing. Try to use relative paths if you can, aka `./icon.png` or `../Images/icon.png` to retain portability.

Finally, using `background-image` is preferred here, since that is the only property you are setting. If you define `background` elsewhere, you might override the image you've set!

Answer (score 0):

and accidentally different ways for a picture? and why this way? usually the images are in respective folders-directory project

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your images are located where the html file and css are located, change your css to the following :

```
.boxa {
  display: block;
  background:url(App-Google-icon.png);
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  -webkit-transition:width 0.1s, height 0.1s, background-color 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition:width 0.1s, height 0.1s, background-color 0.4s, transform 0.1s;
}

.boxa:hover {
  background:url(App-Google-icon.png);
  width:1024px;
  height:1024px;
}
```